Get original error message and stack trace in topmost orchestrator In Azure functions app (isolated mode)
I have an Azure functions application (NET8.0, isolated mode, Core Tools Version 4.0.5801, Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669). At the moment of writing this question all packages are up to date.
There are many orchestration and activity functions, and one "main" orchestrator which starts the invocation chain. This orchestrator should also be able to catch exception and provide original error message and stack trace. The demo code:
[Function(nameof(MainOrchestrator))]
public static async Task MainOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    string[] cities = ["Seattle", "London"];
    try
    {
        foreach (var city in cities)
        {
            await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof(CityOrchestrator), city);
        }
    }
    catch (TaskFailedException ex)
    {
        // inspect the exception here
    }

}

[Function(nameof(CityOrchestrator))]
public static async Task CityOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context, string city, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    string[] postfixes = ["a", "b"];

    foreach (var postfix in postfixes)
    {
        await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(SayHello), input: $"{city}-{postfix}");
    }
}

[Function(nameof(SayHello))]
public static async Task SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string cityName, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    if (cityName == "London-b") throw new Exception("Fire in London!");
}

[Function("Orchestration_HttpStart")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
            nameof(MainOrchestrator));
    return await client.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
}

The error happens in "SayHello" activity. If I catch it in "CityOrchestrator" then I can get what I need from the "FailureDetails" property. But if I do than in main orchestrator then failure details show me message "Task 'SayHello' (#1) failed with an unhandled exception: Fire in London!" (okay, it is close to original) and stack trace related to execution framework:

at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options)
at AzureBackground.Orchestration.CityOrchestrator(TaskOrchestrationContext context, String city, FunctionContext executionContext) in C:\bb_projekt\DociaBackground\AzureBackgroundTasks\AzureBackground\Orchestration.cs:line 42
at AzureBackground.DirectFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in C:\bb_projekt\DociaBackground\AzureBackgroundTasks\AzureBackground\obj\Debug\net8.0\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators.FunctionExecutorGenerator\GeneratedFunctionExecutor.g.cs:line 70
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore.FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in /mnt/vss/work/1/s/extensions/Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore/src/FunctionsMiddleware/FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware.cs:line 38
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.FunctionsOrchestrator.EnsureSynchronousExecution(FunctionContext functionContext, FunctionExecutionDelegate next, FunctionsOrchestrationContext orchestrationContext) in //src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/FunctionsOrchestrator.cs:line 81
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.FunctionsOrchestrator.RunAsync(TaskOrchestrationContext context, Object input) in /_/src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/FunctionsOrchestrator.cs:line 51
at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationShim.Execute(OrchestrationContext innerContext, String rawInput)

Original stack trace is very important for business logic and I should be able to get it somehow in the code. How can I do that?
Thank you in advance!

Being unable to solve the problem in elegant way I developed a solution based on a middleware class. Not beauty, but solves my problem. I share it for those who experience same problems.
First of all I add a middleware for activity functions in Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication(app =>
{
    app.UseWhen<ErrorMiddleware>(context =>
    {
        var triggerType = context.FunctionDefinition.InputBindings.Values.First(a => a.Type.EndsWith("Trigger")).Type;
        return triggerType == "activityTrigger";
    });

})
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddSingleton<IErrorStorage>(s =>
    {
        return new ErrorStorageTable(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage"), "MyErrorRegistry");
    });
});

The middleware catches exceptions and stores their details into a configured storage (Azure table storage in my case), under unique correlation Id. Then builds a marker based on this Id and throws another error using the marker as the message.
internal class ErrorMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<ErrorMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly IErrorStorage _errorStorage;

    public ErrorMiddleware(ILogger<ErrorMiddleware> logger, IErrorStorage errorStorage)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _errorStorage = errorStorage;
    }


    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Exception in {n}", context.FunctionDefinition.Name);

            // Registering exception
            ErrorDetails details = ErrorDetails.FromException(ex);
            ErrorCorrelationId id = ErrorCorrelationId.NewId();
            await _errorStorage.RegisterErrorAsync(id, details);
            throw new Exception(ExceptionParser.CreateMarker(id), ex);
        }

    }
}

At the end, there is a try-catch block in the main orchestration. In case of an exception its message could contain the correlation marker with Id. In such case I can read error details from the storage.
try
{
    job.ReturnValue = 
        await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<string?>(taskName, input: job);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if(ExceptionParser.TryGetCorrelationId(ex, out var correlationId))
    {
        job.ErrorCorrelationId = correlationId;
    }
    else
    {
        job.ErrorDetails = ErrorDetails.FromException(ex);
    }
}

I'm sure my solution is not perfect, but this is better than nothing. Hope it will save some time for other people.
